# Uniform limit with respect to a parameter

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence

Given a real function such that for every fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$,  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n,t)=0$, can I express this in English saying that $f(n,t)$ vanishes as $n\rightarrow\infty$, *uniformly* in $t$? My doubts are about the use of the word *uniformly* in the weak sense of a point-wise limit that is always the same for all $t$, when dealing with parametric limits, as it could mean something stronger, that is uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $(f_n(t))$. So in conclusion, can the adverb *uniformly* be used in this weak sense in English? Or it is only used for uniform limit of sequences of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the formal definitions:

We say that $f_t(n)$ convergence point-wise to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ if,

$$\forall_{\varepsilon>0} \forall_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\exists_{N\in\mathbb{N}} \forall_{n>N} |f_t(n)-0|<\varepsilon$$

We say that $f_t(n)$ convergence uniformly to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ if,

$$\forall_{\varepsilon>0} \exists_{N\in\mathbb{N}} \forall_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \forall_{n>N} |f_t(n)-0|<\varepsilon$$

In other words the convergence is uniform if you can find the same $N$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Examples:

For instance the map $f_t(n) = \frac{t}{n}$ converge point-wise to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ but not uniformly (because you need a larger $N$ the more $t$ grows).

Comment: That is pretty much what I was about to write when I got disturbed.

Comment: This is what I also knew in Italian, so you confirm that using *uniformly* in that context would convey the wrong information. Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: @GiordanoGiambartolomei Yes, the term "for every fixed $t$" exactly means that the convergence is point-wise.